# Why does Android's NumberFormat use a comma as a decimal separator for Australia?

Tags: java, android, locale, number-formatting

Using the `android.icu.text.NumberFormat` class:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat =  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale("en", "AU")); 
numberFormat.isGroupingUsed = true
String number = numberFormat.format(123456)
```

will produce `123,456`, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator), Australia uses a point `.` as the decimal separator. Why is NumberFormat behaving that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number `123456` does not have decimals. You're observing the thousands grouping symbol `,`, not the decimal point.

Comment: Oops. That's somewhat embarassing :D Thanks.